# How to delete columns by headers name

Tags: vba, excel

*Error Type mismatch on following line*

***`vMatch = Application.Match(vHeaders(i), Sheets(Sht).Rows(lColumn), 0)`***

When debug, code is showing  `vMatch = Empty` what am I missing?

```
Sub TestArray()
    Dim vHeaders() As Variant
    Dim vMatch As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim lColumn As Long

    Set Sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

    lColumn = Sht.UsedRange.Columns.Count

    vHeaders = Array("Branch", "Account#", "Route Name", "Driver Number", _
                  "Reference2", "Reference3", "Stop Number", "Phone", "Delivery Time", _
                  "Stop Close Time", "POD Contact Name", "Latitude", "Longitude", _
                  "Status", "Service", "ASN Create Date", "ASN Date", "StopID", _
                  "Load Scan", "Delivery Scan", "Exception", "Exception Time")


    For i = LBound(vHeaders) To UBound(vHeaders) Step 1
        vMatch = Application.Match(vHeaders(i), Sheets(Sht).Rows(lColumn), 0)
        If IsNumeric(vMatch) Then Sheets(Sht).Columns(vMatch).delete
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace this lines

```
    vMatch = Application.Match(vHeaders(i), Sheets(Sht).Rows(lColumn), 0)
    If IsNumeric(vMatch) Then Sheets(Sht).Columns(vMatch).delete
```

With

```
    vMatch = Application.Match(vHeaders(i), Sht.Rows(1), 0)
    If IsNumeric(vMatch) Then Sht.Columns(vMatch).Delete
```

Also no need for the below code and declaration

```
lColumn = Sht.UsedRange.Columns.Count
```